# Java equivalent of Perl function to print only unique lines?

Tags: java

Trying to find a java equivalent of this line of Perl code:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{$_}++'
```

Did some looking around but to no avail!
Cheers,
Ger

Comment: Look at `Map#putIfAbsent`. It will return `null` only the first time it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's trivia-like question, not a real production problem, then I suppose that Java 8 is allowed.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PrintUnique {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines().distinct()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Java 6 solution would be like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PrintUnique {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(lines.add(line))
                System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it stores unique lines in the memory, but repeating lines are just skipped.

Comment: (The Perl solution only reads the distinct lines into memory, but that's probably not that big a difference)

Comment: It actually is a production problem, all be it a poorly phrased one. Need solution in java 6...

Comment: Added Java 6 solution